# LINQ query dropping includes when adding `.Contains()` in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a somewhat complex query I'm trying to build in Linq (EntityFramework Core 2.1), and I hit behavior I can't comprehend. The below query runs well and seemingly efficiently:

```
var q = (
from n in TaskUpdates.Include(t => t.Status).Include("Task").Include("Task.Requirement").Include("User").Include("User.Employee")
where n.User.Employee.EmployeeNumber == 765448466
group n by n.UpdateDate into tu
select tu.OrderByDescending(t=>t.UpdateDate).FirstOrDefault()
)
.Select(x => x.Task.Requirement);
```

This works as I'd expect, does all the joins I want and includes the expected fields in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT [t].[TaskUpdateID], [t].[Active], [t].[TaskId], [t].[Notes], [t].[StatusId], [t].[UpdateDate], [t].[UserId], [t.Task].[TaskID], [t.Task].[Active], [t.Task].[CreatedDate], [t.Task].[RequirementId], [t.Task].[UserId], [t.Task.Requirement].[RequirementID], [t.Task.Requirement].[Active], [t.Task.Requirement].[Description], [t.Task.Requirement].[Hours], [t.Task.Requirement].[Link], [t.Task.Requirement].[Name], [t.Task.Requirement].[RequirementTypeId], [t.Task.Requirement].[ExternalId], [t.Task.Requirement].[SortOrder], [t.Status].[StatusId], [t.Status].[Active], [t.Status].[IsComplete], [t.Status].[Title], [t.User].[UserId], [t.User].[Active], [t.User].[Created], [t.User].[EmployeeNumber], [t.User].[LastLogin], [t.User].[LastUpdated], [t.User.Employee].[EMPLOYEENUMBER], [t.User.Employee].[BEGINDATE], [t.User.Employee].[CITY], [t.User.Employee].[EMPLOYEETYPE], [t.User.Employee].[ENDDATE], [t.User.Employee].[FIRST_NAME], [t.User.Employee].[GENERATION_SUFFIX], [t.User.Employee].[STATUS], [t.User.Employee].[LAST_NAME], [t.User.Employee].[MIDDLE_NAME], [t.User.Employee].[MOBILE], [t.User.Employee].[ORGCODE], [t.User.Employee].[PHONE_NUMBER], [t.User.Employee].[PRIMARYEMAIL], [t.User.Employee].[STATE], [t.User.Employee].[STREET], [t.User.Employee].[TITLE], [t.User.Employee].[ZIPCODE], [t.User.Employee].[BUILDING], [t.User.Employee].[ROOM]
FROM [TaskUpdates] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Tasks] AS [t.Task] ON [t].[TaskId] = [t.Task].[TaskID]
LEFT JOIN [Requirements] AS [t.Task.Requirement] ON [t.Task].[RequirementId] = [t.Task.Requirement].[RequirementID]
INNER JOIN [Status] AS [t.Status] ON [t].[StatusId] = [t.Status].[StatusId]
INNER JOIN [Users] AS [t.User] ON [t].[UserId] = [t.User].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [DirectoryPeople] AS [t.User.Employee] ON [t.User].[EmployeeNumber] = [t.User.Employee].[EMPLOYEENUMBER]
WHERE [t.User.Employee].[EMPLOYEENUMBER] = 765448466
ORDER BY [t].[UpdateDate]
GO
```

(I'm using LINQPad to experiment with this query and get the SQL.) In particular, the ending `.Select(...)` method correctly returns the `Requirement` object from the query.

What baffles me is if I want to make this query return data for multiple employees, and I change the `where` clause like so:

```
var employeeNumbers = new int[] { 765448466 };

var q = (
from n in TaskUpdates.Include(t => t.Status).Include("Task").Include("Task.Requirement").Include("User").Include("User.Employee")
//where n.User.Employee.EmployeeNumber == 765448466
where employeeNumbers.Contains(n.User.Employee.EmployeeNumber)
group n by n.UpdateDate into tu
select tu.OrderByDescending(t=>t.UpdateDate).FirstOrDefault()
)
.Select(x => x.Task.Requirement);
```

This changes the resulting SQL `WHERE` clause exactly as I would expect, but it now completely ignores the `Include`s in the `from` clause:

```sql
SELECT [t].[TaskUpdateID], [t].[Active], [t].[TaskId], [t].[Notes], [t].[StatusId], [t].[UpdateDate], [t].[UserId]
FROM [TaskUpdates] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Users] AS [t.User] ON [t].[UserId] = [t.User].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [DirectoryPeople] AS [t.User.Employee] ON [t.User].[EmployeeNumber] = [t.User.Employee].[EMPLOYEENUMBER]
WHERE [t.User.Employee].[EMPLOYEENUMBER] IN (765448466)
ORDER BY [t].[UpdateDate]
GO
```

(only joins as necessary to execute the `where`) and the result of the final `.Select(...)` now returns `null`.

Is this known behavior, with or without explanation? Am I using the `Include` directives incorrectly, or is there a better way/place for them to go that will resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain the cause, I would suspect EF is going down a different translation path with the Contains and missing the Includes, however as you can see it's not translating the GroupBy at all, so it can definitely be reworked to match more the EF style.

```
TaskUpdates
  .Include(x => x.Task)
      .ThenInclude(x => x.Requirement)
  .Where(x => employeeNumbers.Contains(x.User.Employee.EmployeeNumber))
  .ToList()
  .GroupBy(x => x.UpdateDate)
  .Select(x => new {
      UpdateDate = x.Key,
      FirstRequirement = x.First().Task.Requirement
  })
  .ToList();
```

This should translate the statements before the first ToList into SQL, populate the results in-memory and allow C# to do the groupby and aggregates on the whole object which SQL would be unable to do.

Comment: Thanks, but, I'm working up to a query that returns 20-100 users, and the potential tasks and requirements are preassigned and somewhat large in number--I'm not keen to retrieve the whole thing via `.ToList()` if I can at all help it... I eventually hope to do aggregates in the LINQ that will be computed on the DB side also... so this solution goes in the opposite direction I was hoping. But thanks for pointing out the lack of a group-by... I was so confused by the loss of the joins I didn't even notice that the rest of the query was being done client-side!